# String from message.obj not working for comparison condition

Tags: java, android

I getting a message from Message class and putting it in a string ss, Now everytime i get the string `HOME` i'm sending a message dir, but it never sends the message

I'm not sure why but the first condition is never satisfied even though ss is `HOME` which is proof because `tv.settext` becomes `HOME` (I've tested this multiple times)

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readField);
ss=(String) message.obj;
if(ss.equals("HOME")) {
   Message msg = Message.obtain();
   msg.obj = dir;
   writeHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}
else {
   tv.setText(ss);
}
```

Comment: You need to show the writeHandler code.

Comment: The `setText` only occurs if they are NOT equal, so something else must be amiss with your value.  Where's the code that sets the `message.obj`?  Also the idiom is to put the constant first so `"HOME".equals(ss)` is the preferred usage.

Comment: Do a `tv.setText(Arrays.toString(ss.codePoints().toArray()));` Should give: `[72, 79, 77, 69]` Maybe there is a space, zero instead of O, Cyrrilic H.

Comment: `TextView` will transform strings to uppercase by default, so it's possible that `ss` is really `home` or `Home`, even though it displays as `HOME`.

Comment: No actually i'm getting exactly how i want it on the textview
It's just that the if condition is not working

Answer (score 0):

Reading part of my code to understand the above code

```
/**
 * Return data read from the socket, or a blank string.
 */
private String read() {

    String s = "";

    try {
        // Check if there are bytes available
        if (inStream.available() > 0) {

            // Read bytes into a buffer
            byte[] inBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = inStream.read(inBuffer);

            // Convert read bytes into a string
            s = new String(inBuffer, "ASCII");
            s = s.substring(0, bytesRead);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Read failed!", e);
    }

    return s;
}

 //Under Message class
 //Message coding
 private void sendToReadHandler(String s) {

    Message msg = Message.obtain();
    msg.obj = s;
    readHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    Log.i(TAG, s);
}

/**
 * Send complete messages from the rx_buffer to the read handler.
 */
private void parseMessages() {

    // Find the first delimiter in the buffer
    int inx = rx_buffer.indexOf(DELIMITER);

    // If there is none, exit
    if (inx == -1)
        return;

    // Get the complete message
    String s = rx_buffer.substring(0, inx);

    // Remove the message from the buffer
    rx_buffer = rx_buffer.substring(inx + 1);

    // Send to read handler
    sendToReadHandler(s);

    // Look for more complete messages
    parseMessages();
}

public void run() {

    // Attempt to connect and exit the thread if it failed
    try {
        connect();
        sendToReadHandler("CONNECTED");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to connect!", e);
        sendToReadHandler("CONNECTION FAILED");
        disconnect();
        return;
    }

    // Loop continuously, reading data, until thread.interrupt() is called
    while (!this.isInterrupted()) {

        // Make sure things haven't gone wrong
        if ((inStream == null) || (outStream == null)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Lost bluetooth connection!");
            break;
        }

        // Read data and add it to the buffer
        String s = read();
        if (s.length() > 0)
            rx_buffer += s;

        // Look for complete messages
        parseMessages();
    }

    // If thread is interrupted, close connections
    disconnect();
    sendToReadHandler("DISCONNECTED");
}
}
```